# Retrieve DOM-Tree until a specific element as string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, tree

I want to retrieve the whole DOM Tree, from the initial HTML to a specific element. Specifically it should look like this:

[Chrome DOM Tree View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDjiQ.png)

That's from Chromes DOM Inspector. 
I want to use it in jQuery afterwards by using this string as a selector.

So far I am able to retrieve one certain element (with an onclick event, which is exactly what I need in my project) and its parent element, but not the whole tree to this point.

I hope you can help me, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Use `prevAll` and `parent` to traverse up the dom tree.

Comment: I can retrieve the elements with `parents()` but they are returned as DOM elements, not as a string as I would like them to be. 
`.toString()` won't work also, as it  returns "[object HTMLHtmlElement]"

Comment: Try using `$('selector')[0].nodeName.toLowerCase()`